# Storing a Dictionary with polymorphic values in mongoDB using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Let us say we have a key with values which are polymorphic in their sense. Consider the next sample project:

```
public class ToBeSerialized
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId MongoId;
    public IDictionary<string, BaseType> Dictionary;
}

public abstract class BaseType
{
}

public class Type1 : BaseType
{
    public string Value1;
}

public class Type2:BaseType
{
    public string Value1;
    public string Value2;
}


internal class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var objectToSave = new ToBeSerialized
                               {
                                   MongoId = ObjectId.GenerateNewId(),
                                   Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, BaseType>
                                                    {
                                                        {"OdEd1", new Type1 {Value1="value1"}},
                                                        {
                                                            "OdEd2",
                                                            new Type1 {Value1="value1"}
                                                            }
                                                    }
                               };
        string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost/Serialization";
        var mgsb = new MongoUrlBuilder(connectionString);
        var MongoServer = MongoDB.Driver.MongoServer.Create(mgsb.ToMongoUrl());
        var MongoDatabase = MongoServer.GetDatabase(mgsb.DatabaseName);
        MongoCollection<ToBeSerialized> mongoCollection = MongoDatabase.GetCollection<ToBeSerialized>("Dictionary");
        mongoCollection.Save(objectToSave);

        ToBeSerialized received = mongoCollection.FindOne();
    }
}
```

Sometimes when I try to deserialize it, I get deserialization errors like **"Unknown discriminator value 'The name of concrete type'".** What am I doing wrong? If every value stores a _t why cannot it map it correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Driver should know about all discriminators to deserialize any class without errors. There are two ways to do it:

1.Register it globally during app start:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Type1>();
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Type2>();
```

2.Or though the [BsonKnownTypes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-Specifyingknowntypes) attibute:

```
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(Type1), typeof(Type2)]
 public class BaseType
 {

 }
```

If you will use #1 or #2 your deserialization will work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You have to register which types inherit from `BaseClass` before attempting to deserialize them. This will happen automatically if you serialize first, which is probably why the error occurs only sometimes.

You can register derived types using an attribute:

```
[BsonDiscriminator(Required = true)]
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(DerivedType1), typeof(DerivedType2))]
public class BaseClass { ... }

public class DerivedType1 : BaseClass { ... }
```

Comment: Well, Andrew's answer is more complete. I have to admit I forgot the syntax of the `BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap` call, and when I had looked it up, Andrew already posted his answer. I'd generally favor the more complete answer, because other users will probably take a look at the accepted answer first.