# Serialize object dictionary in C# MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, dictionary, serialization

I'm implementing a custom serializer for a class that contains a `<string, object>` dictionary for the sole purpose of stripping out the `_t` and `_v` fields that come with serializing `object`s by default (I don't care about deserialization).

Below is an example for the case when the `object` value is a string array:

```
class MyClass {
    Dictionary<string, object> maps;
}

class MySerializer : SerializerBase<MyClass> {
    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, MyClass value) {
        context.Writer.WriteStartDocument();
        context.Writer.WriteName("Maps");
        foreach (var kvp in value.maps) {
            context.Writer.WriteStartDocument();
            context.Writer.WriteName(kvp.Key);
            Type t = kvp.Value.GetType();
            if (t == typeof(string[])) {
                context.Writer.WriteStartArray();
                foreach (string s in (string[])kvp.Value) {
                    context.Writer.WriteString(s);
                }
                context.Writer.WriteEndArray();
            }
            else {
                // More type checks here
            }
            context.Writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }
        context.Writer.WriteEndDocument();
    }
```

Expected/desired output:

```
Maps: {
    key1: [value11, value12, value3],
    key2: [value21, value22, value23]
}
```

However, all I get is an error, saying that I can't use `WriteStartDocument()`:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'WriteStartDocument can only be
>   called when State is Initial or Value or ScopeDocument or Done, not
>   when State is Name'

How can this be done?

**Edit:** It would happen that after 5+ hours of searching, trying code, and then finally posting this question, I revisit an answer I had already looked over and then find out that it can be applied to my situation. Adding onto [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31096316/1014005) solution:

```
public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, MyClass value) {
    var jsonDoc = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
    var bsonDoc = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(jsonDoc);
    bsonDoc.Remove("Id"); // Remove unnecessary ID field that gets generated from the JSON
    RawBsonDocument rawDoc = new RawBsonDocument(bsonDoc.ToBson());
    context.Writer.WriteRawBsonDocument(rawDoc.Slice);
}
```

That said, I'm still curious as to how we can serialize into nested maps manually. `WriteStartDocument` after `WriteName` is still the only thing that makes sense to me, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You probably should be considering what others have already done: [Dictionary<string, object>-to-BsonDocument conversion omitting _t field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786403/dictionarystring-object-to-bsondocument-conversion-omitting-t-field)

Comment: @NeilLunn I've seen that question but I couldn't/don't know how to apply it to the serializer class. The OP of that question just wanted to get a BSON document. I want to write the document to `context.Writer` but that only accepts a `MongoDB.Bson.IO.IByteBuffer` and I can't find anything to convert from a document to that.