# Deserializing interface in MongoDB using C# - Unknown discriminator value

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

First of all, I use the current version of MongoDB (3.2) and its C#-driver (2.2.3).
I have the following classes:

```
public class Item
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    // ... some other properties

    public Data Data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string BaseType { get; set; }
    public IBaseData BaseData { get; set; }
}

public interface IBaseData 
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Version { get; set; }
    IDictionary<string, object> PayloadData { get; }
}
```

Then I have some different implementations of the IBaseData interface:

```
public class EventData : IBaseData
{
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, object> PayloadData { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class ExceptionData : IBaseData
{
    // Implementation of the interface and some additional properties
}
```

Storing an Item-object to MongoDB is no problem and it seems that everything is correct. Mongo uses the `_t` to determine the type of `IBaseData` (e.g. `EventData`). When I try to retrieve the data for the first time, it works perfectly which means I have the complete tree of objects. **When I restart the application** and post the same request again, I get the following error:

> An error occurred while deserializing the Data property of class Domain.Objects.Item: An error occurred while deserializing the BaseData property of class Domain.Objects.Data: Unknown discriminator value 'EventData'.

After dropping the Mongo-database and starting the application, it works again as expected.

Google gave me different approaches but nothing helped me:

[Storing a Dictionary with polymorphic values in mongoDB using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138330/storing-a-dictionary-with-polymorphic-values-in-mongodb-using-c-sharp)

[Unknown discriminator value 'MyEvent'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451422/unknown-discriminator-value-myevent)

[Deserialize object as an interface with MongoDB C# Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561809/deserialize-object-as-an-interface-with-mongodb-c-sharp-driver?rq=1)

I would like to work with property annotations like `[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(Type1), typeof(Type2)]`, but this just works for classes.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Have you considered using dynamic BSonDocument instead of poly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I partially solved the problem for me by adding a classmap in Program.cs (or other application-start class):

```
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<EventData>(cm =>
        {
            cm.AutoMap();
            cm.SetDiscriminator("EventData");
        });

        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<ExceptionData>(cm =>
        {
            cm.AutoMap();
            cm.SetDiscriminator("ExceptionData");
        });
```

If somebody find a way to **work with annotations**, please answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Setting the Discriminator Value section of MongoDB C# Driver documentation on polymorphism](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/bson/mapping/polymorphism/#setting-the-discriminator-value), it looks like annotating your classes with `[BsonDiscriminator("EventData")]` and `[BsonDiscriminator("ExceptionData")]`, respectively, should be equivalent to the example from your answer.